# OpenGL ES 1.1 clearColor drawing

Tags: ios, opengl-es

How can I draw with [UIColor clearColor] in OpenGL ES 1.1? I want to create eraser tool...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a masked image. There are many ways to do this and here is what worked for me:

I created an image that has a black circle and all the rest is transparent. I create a texture from this image and draw it as a simple textured square but using this blend func:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_ZERO, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Do not forget to enable blend and after the draw call is done restore your blend func (or disable the blend if you don't use it anywhere else)

Comment: Thanks! and it will be work if I have a transparent background?

Comment: Note that if you're just working with binary transparency (0 or 1), then it's probably much better to use **glAlphaFunc** than **glBlendFunc** for performance. Using blending implies that you want to combine source with destination colors, and thus it has to sample the framebuffer before the pixel can be drawn. Using alpha test tells it to just discard a pixel, rather than sampling a pixel from the framebuffer and redrawing it. Both have the same result, but alpha test is easier on the GPU.

Comment: TIM: But if you consider that the render buffer is already full, would alpha func be able to clear a part of that render buffer?

miksayer: You didn't actually told us what your situation is and what are you trying to do. In the solution I gave it to you, consider you have an UIView of green color on witch there is an openGL subview that is filled with any shapes and colors. By applying this methode you will se a green shapes where you draw the mask texture.

Comment: @MaticOblak but I have a transparent background view :( what i will see in this case?

Comment: I still do not know what are you trying to create. What you will see is if you have a clear color is black or probably that apple grey background. If this is a drawing app you will probably add some paper like background and you will se that. You should try to explain what are you trying to do.

Comment: @MaticOblak Yeah, it is drawing app, but I have an image as background(it is UIImageView) and I have transparent canvas above

Comment: Ok, so you draw to canvas and then erase it with the tool described in this answer and you will see the image view's image wherever the canvas is erased.